# Centred element off-centre after php

Tags: css

I'm getting a really confusing positioning problem. I have an `<img>` element with 
`display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;`, which ought to centre it. The problem is that it's not centred within its container, but rather appears to be centred within the left half of its container.

Complicating matters, this only occurs following a linked php file

```
<div class="header">
...
<nav id="menu" class="topnav">
<ul>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="alexandria.html"><br style="clear: both;"/>Alexandria<br style="clear: both;"/><span>Referencing Manager</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="ceryneian.html"><br style="clear: both;"/>Ceryneian<br style="clear: both;"/><span>Research Browser</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="blog"><br style="clear: both;"/>Blog<br style="clear: both;"/><span>Thoughts</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="about.html"><br style="clear: both;"/>About<br style="clear: both;"/><span>Our Team</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

- if I remove this it works fine. **Edit** I've been testing my CSS, and it appears that if I remove the `float:right;` on the `<ul>`it works - I don't know why though, and I want to keep the float if possible.

Here's the page in question http://fireoak.3owl.com/404.html - thanks in advance if you can be of any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add foll0wing CSS to your content div  line -100(main_large.css)  

    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin: 75px auto auto;

And css for img
    position: relative; (line 17 main_large.css)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent element a width (`width:100%;` for example), then give the child element that you want to center `margin: 0 auto;` which should center it for you.

Also, if you get issues when including the header.php then make sure your HTML is valid in that file.

Comment: The parent elements has a width, and `margin: 0 auto;` isn't working either.